# Reordering an object in javascript using underscore

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have json that looks like this (copied from dev tools inspector)

```
salePurchases
  salesPeriods: Array[2]
    0: Object
      data: Array[5]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        4: Object
      period: "2011"
    1: Object
      data: Array[5]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        4: Object
      period: "2012"

  purchasePeriods: Array[2]
    0: Object
      data: Array[5]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        4: Object
      period: "2011"
    2: Object
      data: Array[5]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        4: Object
      period: "2012"
```

I want to pull it apart and make it creat a new object that looks like this -

```
OrderedByYears:
  2011:
    data: Array[10]
      0: Object // this should be the 1st item from the salesPeriods array with a period of 2011
      1: Object // this should be the 1st item from the purchasePeriods array with a period of 2011
      2: Object
      3: Object
      4: Object
      5: Object
      6: Object
      7: Object
      8: Object
      9: Object  // this should be the 5th item from the salesPeriods array with a period of 2011
      10: Object // this should be the 5th item from the purchasePeriods array with a period of 2011
  2012:
    data: Array[10]
      0: Object // this should be the 1st item from the salesPeriods array with a period of 2012
      1: Object // this should be the 1st item from the purchasePeriods array with a period of 2012
      2: Object
      3: Object
      4: Object
      5: Object
      6: Object
      7: Object
      8: Object
      9: Object // this should be the 5th item from the salesPeriods array with a period of 2012
      10: Object // this should be the 5th item from the purchasePeriods array with a period of 2012
```

I'm basing the arrangement by the key 'period' and then alternating between joining each array together but alternating between the relavant object salesPeriods and purchasePeriods.

I'm sure this is relatively simple using underscore. Anyone know if it's an easy thing to do? Explaining the steps involved would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're stuck and this is not just a 'write this code for me' question - where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck on the approach I should take, I'm going to try John's answer below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used underscore.js, but it looks like it maps nicely to the general concepts.  Here is the general approach you would want:

1. `concat` the salesPeriods and purchasePeriods together into one list.
2. `groupBy` the `period` value in each of the objects.
3. `map` the grouped results into the object shape you want.

You might want to throw some `sort` statements in there, depending upon your goals.

Comment: Amazing, thanks very much. I think I've achieved what I wanted without the need to map. Excuse my ignorance, but what are the benefits of mapping>

Comment: @Finnnn: Care to share your solution?

Comment: @Finnnn: Mapping is just the common method for restructuring an object.  Sometimes you can use  other methods to alter the objects, but that's more of a side effect rather than the actual intent of the function.  So, I listed map in order to make the process clear.

Comment: @Finnnn: And since your target output is a plain object, indexed by the year, you might consider one additional step after a `map`: a `reduce` (also known as a `fold`), which is a technique for combining a list of items into a single output.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have an approach that's working for you.  I've been working on a **[Functional Programming Library](https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda)** in Javascript, and this is how I would handle the problem with that library:

```
var weave = compose(flatten, zip);
reduce(function(obj, period) {
    obj[period.year] = {data: period.data};
    return obj;
}, {}, map(function(year) {
    var getMatch = find(function(period) {return period.period === year;});
    return {year: year, data: weave(getMatch(salePurchases.salesPeriods).data, 
                                    getMatch(salePurchases.purchasePeriods).data)};
}, pluck("period", salePurchases.salesPeriods)));
```

Equivalents to all of the core functions used are also available in Underscore, although in most cases, the parameter order is different.  So with **[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#find)** you could do it like this:

```
var weave = _.compose(_.flatten, _.zip);
_.reduce(_.map(_.pluck(salePurchases.salesPeriods, "period"), function(year) {
    var getMatch = function(period) {return period.period === year;}
    return {year: year, data: weave(_.find(salePurchases.salesPeriods, getMatch).data, 
                                    _.find(salePurchases.purchasePeriods, getMatch).data)};
}), function(obj, period) {
    obj[period.year] = {data: period.data};
    return obj;
}, {});
```

You can see this in action with **[Ramda](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/NUuY4/)** or with **[Underscore](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/NUuY4/2/)** on JSFiddle.

The main idea is that I would start with a list of years, plucked off the salesPeriods.  (This is assuming your data is representative, and all years needed would appear in both lists, and also that the sales periods and purchase periods are both comprehensive.)  Then, using `map`, I would weave together the salesPeriod and purchase periods for each year, returning an object with a year, and an array of intermingled data.  To turn this into your expected output, I would `reduce` this list, by assigning the relevant year property of a new object to an object whose `data` property was that intermingled data.

This technique allows for little error-checking along the way, but is quite compact.